npmInstall FAILED with jdk 17 and gradle 7.4
I am in process of migrating jdk 11 to jdk 17, and updating gradle version from 6.6.1 to 7.4
After changing versions, I tried making war using gradle war command but it failed at this point -
> Task :project:npmInstall FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':project:npmInstall' (type 'NpmInstallTask').
  - In plugin 'com.moowork.gradle.node.NodePlugin' type 'com.moowork.gradle.node.task.NpmInstallTask' property 'args' is missing an input or output annotation.
    
    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.moowork.gradle.node.NodePlugin' type 'com.moowork.gradle.node.task.NpmInstallTask' property 'result' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

I am new developer please help me what all changes do I need to make.
below is my build.gradle file -
buildscript {
    repositories {........}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-grunt-plugin:0.13'
        classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.12'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.moowork.grunt'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

node {
    version = '16.19.1'
    distBaseUrl = 'https://somelink'
    download = true
    workDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
}

grunt {
    workDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
    colors = true
    bufferOutput = false 
}

grunt_bowercopy.dependsOn 'npmInstall'
grunt_copy.dependsOn 'npmInstall'

war.dependsOn ':project-ui:buildAngularApp'
war.dependsOn grunt_bowercopy
war.dependsOn grunt_copy
war.dependsOn grunt_less
war.dependsOn grunt_stylus

there is a build.gradle file of project-ui -
buildscript {
    repositories {....}
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.node-gradle:gradle-node-plugin:3.4.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.node'

node {
    distBaseUrl = 'https://somelink'
    version = '16.19.1'
    download = true
}

task buildAngularApp {}
buildAngularApp.dependsOn npmInstall
buildAngularApp.dependsOn npm_run_build
test.dependsOn 'npm_run_test-no-watch'



Have you tried following the instructions provided by the error?

@aled yes i followed the link but not much detail is there, it repeating same theory there  property without annotation. But I dont get which property need to be annotated.

The plugin com.moowork.grunt was last released in 2019. It is likely it doesn't support the current version of Gradle or even Java 17. You should try to find a similar plugin that was more recently released and migrate your project to it.

I found similar plugin node-gradle:gradle-node-plugin it did my work.
